# ImageView in LinearLayout does not grow even with layout_weight set

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-glide

I'm using a linearlayout in an AlertDialog. I'm trying to use as much space as possible for the image, so I want to use layout_weight="1" to make it grow. I've been using a plain view before and it worked fine, but since I'm now trying to display an image, I'd like to use an ImageView. But the ImageView always has height 0, unless I initialize it with a specific image. But when I change the image afterwards with Glide, the size shrinks to zero again.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/edit_layout"
        style="@style/TextInputOutlinedStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        android:hint="@string/signature_picker_fullname_hint">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I load the image:

```
Glide.with(this.requireContext())
    .load(this.initialSignature.getUri())
    .into(this.imageView);
```

I've tried playing around with adjustViewBounds and scaleTypes and different timings to load the image, but nothing worked.